# Define variables about Player_HP and Damage

Tags: php, math

The variables created below define the Damage Amount coming from the Player and Opponent. After that, comes the part of LIFE, where each one takes X percentage of life depending on the given DAMAGE. Then, the remaining LIFE of the variables $ player_hp and $ opponent_hp is inserted in DATABASE. (UPDATE says "player_health =?".

Error: Every time I make an attack, it removes LIFE ($ player) and adds MORE LIFE (it should remove until it is negative) in DATABASE to OPPONENT ($ opponent), but simply ADDs more life to the opponent.

```
 Exemp: $player_damage = 1200
        $opponent_damage = 500

        $player_hp = 100(hp) - $opponent_damage  
        $opponent_hp = 100(hp) - $player_damage
```

The database show basically like this:

```
  Player_VIDA = -400
  Opponent_VIDA = 600
```

I've tried user on UPDATE player_health = player_health -?, But it's the same.

My used code:

```
$player_damage = rand(5, $player_status['attack']);
$player_damage = $player_damage - ($opponent_status['defense'] * 0.3);

$opponent_damage = rand(5, $opponent_status['attack']);
$opponent_damage = $opponent_damage - ($player_status['defense'] * 0.3);

//add def to the health and subtract with damaged
$player_hp = round($opponent_damage - $player_status['health']);
$opponent_hp = round($player_damage - $opponent_status['health']);
```

Solution: I need to know why the PLAYER and OPPONENT_HP are positive, they should SUBSTRACT to negative.

Comment: May or may not be related, but, you should never do maths in php (or most other languages) with floating point numbers. [see the warning here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). Instead, multiply all your floats by say 100000 to convert them all to ints, do the subtraction, then divide the result by the same 100000 to convert the result back to a float and optionally round that end result.

Comment: ok, and what do u recomend to do?

Comment: @WesleySmith  ???

Comment: First I would do as described above. Then I would swap the subtraction lines logic. You currently do `$opponent_damage - $player_status['health']` but that should probably be `$player_status['health'] - $opponent_damage` for both of those lines.

Comment: But trust me, you'll want to fix the floating point math issue as described above. If you dont, you will most certainly end up with oddly incorrect calculations in you DB.

Comment: @WesleySmith can u give me just an advice about that points...
About HP....
The advice u gave me.. it's the same... is putting "+" istead of "-" into de Table. Like -600 and 700.

Comment: Honestly, there's not enough information to give a full answer. What number does `health` start at for each character? What are the values of `attack` and `defense` for each character? What code do you use to pull the records for each? What code do you use to update the records for each? If you update your question with those answers, perhaps we could could suggest a full fix